# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe not found in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hive-serde

I am trying to process multicharacter delmiter in hive.

I already created a table with the same successfully

```
create external table showtmp3(doc_name STRING,doc_content STRING) row format SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('field.delim'='#a#') location '/unmesha/OUT';
```

Then I need to issue a query as below.

```
 INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/unmesha/OUT_tmpShowData' SELECT * showtmp3 limit 10;
```

But it is giving me the error below

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:153)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.getConvertedOI(MapOperator.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.setChildren(MapOperator.java:333)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:122)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2018)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.PartitionDesc.getDeserializer(PartitionDesc.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.getConvertedOI(MapOperator.java:297)
    ... 24 more


FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
```

Should I download any jar and put in some location?

Please suggest

Comment: what is the version of hive? `MultiDelimitSerDe` is available only from Hive-0.14.

Comment: I am using hive-0.14.0 itself

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you are looking for: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hive/hive-contrib/0.14.0/org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/serde2/MultiDelimitSerDe.java

You can download the original **jar** from Maven repo: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-contrib/0.14.0

Download this jar file and place it into you hive **/lib** folders of all nodes of your cluster. This should resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

you have to add hive-contrib.jar file to the hive. Run the below command in hive shell.

```
add JAR /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH <version> /jars/hive-contrib.jar
(or)
add jar /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-contrib-<version>.jar;
```