# Insert Records From Hive MultiSerde To Parquet Table in Hive

Tags: hive

I am currently Facing an issue while inserting the data from Hive MultiSerde Table (Multi Character as Delimiter) into a Parquet table and encounter the below error

> org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed,

I have created a Hive Landing Table Which has a MultiCharacter as Delimiter (@#@) and is set as MultiSerde.

I also have a Hive Staging Table which is a Parquet Format and is set as ParquetHiveSerDe.

I can view the data in Hive landing which is a Multidelimiter. However when i'm trying to insert from Landing to Staging (insert into hive_staging.table select * from hive_landing.table), I encounter an error.

Please let me know what am i missing here?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: please provide full exception message from failed container logs. You can find it on job tracker. "return code 2 " is not infomative and impossible to guess what is the reason. Dig for failed container logs

Comment: I'm not having access to the container logs, so cannot view it in detail. But here is what  i got from Infra team. Which says MultiSerde Class is missing.
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask.
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe not found

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe not found

Comment: Any Other way to insert the data from Multiserde table to a Parquet table?

Comment: Sorry just read it: Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe not found ...

Comment: It is already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42452616/2700344 - you need to add Jar with SerDe class you are using, it is not bundled with hive distribution

Comment: @leftjoin Even after adding that jar, i did encounter the same issue again. Can you please recommend if there is any other way to load the data from multiserde to Parquet table?

Comment: If you added jar then it should work, try ADD JAR in hive session

Comment: The same issue means that you added jar in a wrong way or it is a wrong Jar and does not contain class you are using as SerDe